# Mysql: If a specific value exists in join, get the min value of other column

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, suppliers and products_suppliers.

Suppliers:

```
ID | Name     | Priority
 1 | Orange   | 1
 2 | Vodafone | 1
 3 | Telekom  | 2
 4 | Else     | 3
```

In products_supplier I have products with quantities

```
ID_product | Supplierid | Quantity
    100 |        1 | 12
    100 |        2 | 14
    100 |        3 | 10
    100 |        4 | 15
    120 |        3 | 15
    120 |        4 | 10
```

I want to have something like this, directly in SQL

```
if exists "priority=1" in suppliers then return min(qty) where supplier is priority=1
else if exists "priority=2"in suppliers then return min(qty) where supplier is priority=2
else if exists "priority=3" in suppliers then return min(qty) where supplier is priority=3
```

Output should be something like

```
ID_product | Supplierid | Quantity
       100 |        1 | 12
       120 |        3 | 15  
  //even if exists supplier 4 with qty=10,   
    supplier 3 have priority because Red is in front of Blue
```

I did this code, but I am sure there is room for better:

```
SELECT pps.ID_product, min(qty), name, priority
FROM products_suppliers pps
LEFT JOIN suppliers ps on pps.supplierid=ps.id
WHERE 
  productid=100
  AND
  priority = if (exists(SELECT priority FROM suppliers WHERE priority ="1" limit 1), "1", 
        if (exists(SELECT priority FROM suppliers WHERE priority ="2" limit 1), "2", "3")
```

Thanks

Comment: Is this a job for `CASE ... WHEN ... THEN ... WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ... END`?

Comment: I think so, but I do not know how to put it...My interest is to not call the same select several times. I have many predefined values in the tables, not just the four I mentioned

Comment: Can you show what the expected output might be?

Comment: the result should be 12, which is min between (12,14) of the suppliers who are Yellow.

Comment: Where is the `type` column in table `suppliers`?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question to be more clear, and I forgot to change type in priority. first question was with type=(Yellow, Red, Blue) and now I changed to priorty=(1,2,3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I precisely understand your question and using your desired output as a reference, you want to achieve this:

For each product ID, return the Product ID, Supplier ID, and Quantity of the first and highest prioritized supplier.

**Output:**

```
ProductID | SupplierID | Quantity
---------------------------------
100       | 1          | 12
---------------------------------
120       | 3          | 15
```

**Code:**

```
# Return product_id, supplier_id, and quantity based on supplier's priority (1 is highest).
SELECT  ProductID,
        SupplierID,
        Quantity
FROM
(
    SELECT      s.supplier_priority SupplierPriority,
                ps.product_id ProductID,
                s.supplier_id SupplierID,
                ps.quantity Quantity
    FROM        tbl_suppliers s
    INNER JOIN  tbl_products_supplier ps
    ON          s.supplier_id = ps.supplier_id
    GROUP BY    s.supplier_priority,
                ps.product_id
) tbl_sample
GROUP BY ProductID;
```

**Try it:** http://SQLFiddle.com/#!9/ed63b2/3

**Summary:**

The sub-from statement selects the necessary fields from the suppliers table (`tbl_suppliers`) after inner-joining it with the products supplier table (`tbl_products_supplier`). It groups the rows based on the supplier's priority AND product id. The rows are organized so that it displays the rows from least to greatest `SupplierPriority`. Which resulted in this:

```
SupplierPriority | ProductID | SupplierID | Quantity
----------------------------------------------------
1                | 100       | 1          | 12
----------------------------------------------------
1                | 120       | 2          | 40
----------------------------------------------------
2                | 100       | 3          | 10
----------------------------------------------------
2                | 120       | 3          | 15
----------------------------------------------------
3                | 100       | 4          | 15
----------------------------------------------------
3                | 120       | 4          | 10
----------------------------------------------------
```

Then it used by the 'main' select statement. The rows are then grouped by `ProductID`.

Comment: Yep, this is what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solved it more elegant using Php. Since priority is a finite number (let's say less than 10), I did like this:

```
$priority1 = $database->query("
                                SELECT min(qty) as qty
                                FROM products_suppliers pps
                                  LEFT JOIN pin_suppliers ps ON pps.supplierid = ps.id
                                WHERE priority = '1';" )->fetch();
$priority2 = $database->.......WHERE priority = '2';" )->fetch();
 ....
$priorityn = $database->.......WHERE priority = 'n';" )->fetch();

if(!empty($priority1)) do stuff
elseif(!empty($priority2)) do stuff
  ....
elseif(!empty($priorityn)) do stuff
else do stuff
```

If anybody have a solution exclusive with MySql, please post it. Thanks